# Python Call Function from String

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
s = "func"
```

Now suppose there is function called func.
How can i call in Python 2.7 call func when the function name is given as a string?

Answer (score 10):

The safest way to do this:

```
In [492]: def fun():
   .....:     print("Yep, I was called")
   .....:

In [493]: locals()['fun']()
Yep, I was called
```

Depending on the context you might want to use `globals()` instead.

Alternatively you might want to setup something like this:

```
def spam():
    print("spam spam spam spam spam on eggs")

def voom():
    print("four million volts")

def flesh_wound():
    print("'Tis but a scratch")

functions = {'spam': spam,
             'voom': voom,
             'something completely different': flesh_wound,
             }

try:
    functions[raw_input("What function should I call?")]()
except KeyError:
    print("I'm sorry, I don't know that function")
```

You can also pass arguments into your function a la:

```
def knights_who_say(saying):
    print("We are the knights who say {}".format(saying))

functions['knights_who_say'] = knights_who_say

function = raw_input("What is your function? ")
if function == 'knights_who_say':
    saying = raw_input("What is your saying? ")
    functions[function](saying)
else:
    functions[function]()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def func():
    print("hello")
s = "func"
eval(s)()

In [7]: s = "func"

In [8]: eval(s)()
hello
```

**Not recommended!** Just showing you how.

Comment: @BhargavRao, made it a bold statement!

Comment: @MagentaNova, I am pretty certain it does

Comment: @padriac, you're correct, removing comment.

Answer (score 1):

you could use exec. Not recommended but doable.

```
s = "func()"

exec s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a function by passing a string:

```
exec(s + '()')
```

Comment: this won't work as you never call the function

Comment: Yes I see, it will simply return the function object rather than call it. I fixed it.